# Prove that for any two rational numbers $r$ and $s$ with $r ≠ 0$ , $\frac{1}{r} −s$ is rational

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following to problem

> Prove that for any two rational numbers $r$ and $s$ with $r ≠ 0$ , $\frac{1}{r} −s$ is rational

My proof process is as follows (may be incorrect):

> Suppose $r$ and $s$ are rational numbers.
>
> By definition of rational, they can be expressed as a quotient of two
>   integers with a nonzero denominator.
>
> Then $\frac{1}{r}-s$ is equivalent to $\frac{(1- sr)}{r}$

Not sure where to go after this step

Comment: I meant the latter. Just fixed my title

Comment: It is not true that $\frac 1r=\frac {1-sr}r$.  Presumably what you mean to say is $\frac 1r-s=\frac {1-sr}r$.  Earlier in the question you talk about $\frac 1{r-s}$, which is different.  Please get it right.  The fundamental thing is that the rationals are closed under addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division (except by $0$).  This is one case of that.

Comment: Notice you wrote a sentence about $r$ and $s$ being expressed as a quotient of integers and then never did anything with that fact. That's a sign you should examine that part of your argument more closely.

Answer (score 1):

We know that a number is rational if an only if it can be written as a quotent of two integers. Hence as $r,s$ are rationals we have:

$$r = \frac ab; \quad s = \frac cd; \quad a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Now we have that:

$$\frac{1}{r-s} = \frac{1}{\frac ab - \frac cd} = \frac{bd}{ad-bc}$$

From here we easily conclude that $\frac{1}{r-s} \in \mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean $\frac1r-s,$ rather than $\frac1{r-s},$ which is a different thing. Let me know if you don't understand why they are different, or if you meant the other one, or meant something else altogether.

---

Now, if $1-sr$ and $r$ are both integers with $r\neq 0,$ then you're done. That said, it's highly unlikely that this is true.

You need to justify that $\frac{1-rs}{r}$ can be rewritten in the form $\frac mn$ with $m,n$ both integers and $n\ne 0.$

Remember that we can write $r=\frac mn$ and $s=\frac pq,$ where $m,n,p,q$ are integers such that $n$ and $q$ are non-zero. can you take it from there?

Comment: When I rewrite it I have $$ (-mq-np+nq)  \over nq $$ Is this enough justification to represent it as a quotient of two integers?

Comment: Potentially, yes. If you already know that the integers are a group, and have no zero divisors, then you're done. Otherwise, you may have more to justify.

Answer (score 0):

Problems of this level, I'd so the proof is to find two actual integers $n,m$ so that $\frac 1r - s = \frac nm$.

First we are told $r$ is rational and not $0$ so there are integers $a,b$ so that $r = \frac ab$ (and $a\ne 0$).  And we are told $s$ is rational so there are integers $c,d$ so that $s = \frac cd$.

So $\frac 1r - s = \frac 1{\frac ab} -\frac cd$.

Show that we can write that as a fraction with an integer in the numerator and an integer in the denominator.

> $\frac 1{\frac ab} -\frac cd = \frac ba -\frac cd = \frac {bd}{ad} -\frac {ca}{da}= \frac {bd-ca}{ad}$.
>  And integers are closed under multiplication so $bd,ca, da$ are all integers.  And integers are closed under subtraction so $bd-ca$ is an integer.  So as $bd-ca$ is an integer and $da$ is an integer (not equal to $0$... as $d\ne 0$ and $a \ne 0$) the $\frac {bd-ca}{da}$ is a rational number.

Comment: Argh.... zombie thread!  When will I learn?!